# Internet Explorer Not Displaying Correctly With Bootstrap On IBM Websphere

Tags: java, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, websphere

I am encountering an issue that a website built using bootstrap is not displaying correctly in Internet Explore, but only went deployed to IBM Websphere. When displaying the website on a local Apache Tomcat server, it works fine. But when deployed to IBM Websphere, the site display as the mobile version. Anyone know why that is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that Internet Explore is keep switching to Quirks Mode when hitting the production environment but not the local environment...not sure why.

But adding the following `meta` tag to `head` solved the issue

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```